# how to Apply code changes at run time without breaking exectuion

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, runtime

I am in visual studio 2008 and working on a very huge project which takes alot of time to build now when it is running in debug and i make some code changes i want it to incorporate those code changes at run Time. i do understand that this will not be always possible but in some situation it is.

I do know that when i break the execution using break point and then add code then step in again it applies code changes but i want it to apply code changes without breaking execution.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there no way to do the thing you want.

I use following trick in my asp.net application to execute my code change.

- Deatach w3p process from ide ( Go Debug > Deatach all)
- Make changes in code
- Rebuild code
- Attach process again with ide  ( Go Debug > attach process>